# getting cloudflare 429 when trying to simulate request, not getting it when using fiddler

Tags: java, jsoup, fiddler

I've tried to simulate a request using java, but everytime im trying to send it im getting a cloudflare 429, when using fiddler to simulate the same request i get 200.
Java code (not working):

```
Jsoup.connect("")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36")
            .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
            .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")
            .header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
            .header("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document")
            .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9")
            .header("Sec-Fetch-Site", "none")
            .header("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate")
            .header("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1")
            .header("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br")
            .header("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.9,he-IL;q=0.8,he;q=0.7")
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
            .method(Method.GET)
            .execute();
```

Fiddler RAW (Working, 200)

```
GET 
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,he-IL;q=0.8,he;q=0.7
```

Literally using the same header, is there another way cloudflare know I'm not using a Webdriver?

Comment: Redirect the JSoup request so that it also goes through Fiddler and then compare the actually sent request with the saved one.

Comment: Did you ever solve this one? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not on code level. [HTTP status code 429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) means `Too many requests`.

Seems you have sent too many requests and thus triggered the DOS-attack-protection of Cloudflare.

Comment: im not getting a 429 on Fiddler, even when sending request one after another only the java getting blocked

Comment: Then Cloudflare is detecting that you are using Java (e.g. based on the available TLS versions and enabled Ciphers) and disallows usage via Java.

Comment: Can I bypass it somehow? @Rober

Comment: First follow my comment to your question. If the request is identical and works through Fiddler you could try to disable TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 in Java as well as some of the available ciphers (make sure you are using Java 11 and not the old Java 8).